# C++ Create New Window From Console in New Thread (Win32)

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, console, windows-console

**Working environment:**

I am working in VS 2015, and a win32 console.

**Overview:**

I am creating a new window to act as a worker thread to perform some functions that cannot be completed in the console.

The code to create the new window and complete the tasks works well. However it freezes the console.

I have code to create a thread from the console and complete tasks while the console is not frozen. This also works well.

**Problem:**

I am unable to join the two pieces of code, I want to run the new window in the thread so it doesn't block the console.

**Code:**

=============== **int main** ======================

Start thread

```
x = 0;
hPrintMutex = CreateMutex(NULL, false, NULL);

HANDLE hThread1 = (HANDLE)_beginthread(printNumber, 0, &x);
WaitForSingleObject(hThread1, INFINITE);
```

Make new window

```
WNDCLASSEX wndclass = { sizeof(WNDCLASSEX), CS_DBLCLKS, WindowProcedure,
0, 0, GetModuleHandle(0), LoadIcon(0,IDI_APPLICATION),
LoadCursor(0,IDC_ARROW), HBRUSH(COLOR_WINDOW + 1),
0, myclass, LoadIcon(0,IDI_APPLICATION) };

if (RegisterClassEx(&wndclass))
{
    HWND window = CreateWindowEx(0, myclass, "title",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, 0, GetModuleHandle(0), 0);
    if (window)
    {
        ShowWindow(window, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
        MSG msg;
        while (GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0)) DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}
```

======== **outside main** =======================================

code to do something in the new thread

( * The actual contents are just an example, they will be erased and replaced with the window code * )

```
void printNumber(void* pInt)
{

int* xp = (int*)pInt;
while (*xp<100)
{
    WaitForSingleObject(hPrintMutex, INFINITE);

    ++*xp;
    cout << *xp << endl;

    ReleaseMutex(hPrintMutex);
    Sleep(10);
}


}
```

code to create new window and do something

```
long __stdcall WindowProcedure(HWND window, unsigned int msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp)
{
switch (msg)
{

case something: { 

}
default: 

    return DefWindowProc(window, msg, wp, lp);
}
}
```

Any thoughts? Thanks.

***** SOLUTION *****

See my posted solution below, tested and working.

---

Comment: If you don't want to block the interaction with the console then you'll have to use another thread to create the window(s).

Comment: You create a thread and block waiting for it. What is the point of the thread of you block on it. The window appears to be created in the main thread. You use the terms window and thread interchangeably but they are not.

Comment: Starting a thread immediately followed by a wait on the thread handle is a convoluted multithreaded implementation, that has none of the downsides of multithreading (synchronization), but also none of the benefits (concurrency). Doesn't look like you know enough to enter multithreading yet. You need to get a couple of decent books on the subject. Besides, it is not safe to wait on the return value of `_beginthread`. It's not yours. If you want to get ownership of the handle, call `_beingthreadex` instead.

Comment: Thank you for the reply's. I am just learning C++ and am having some difficulties. Could you provide some examples of the solutions your suggesting? Thanks.

Comment: You want us to tell you how to buy a book. That's the solution. You aren't in any position to write this code because your grasp of what is involved is so tenuous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got this working, thought I would post it to help out others who are also starting out and having difficulties

**In your main start the thread**

```
HANDLE myhandle;

myhandle = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(0, 0, &mythread, 0, 0, 0);
```

If your console runs in a loop then you don't need to call WaitForSingleObject, if it doesn't you will need to call it so the console doesn't close.

**Outside the main**

create the thread, and inside the thread you will create your window

```
unsigned int __stdcall mythread(void* data)
{

cout << "/n created monitor window /n";

const char* const myclass = "myclass";

WNDCLASSEX wndclass = { sizeof(WNDCLASSEX), CS_DBLCLKS, WindowProcedure,
    0, 0, GetModuleHandle(0), LoadIcon(0,IDI_APPLICATION),
    LoadCursor(0,IDC_ARROW), HBRUSH(COLOR_WINDOW + 1),
    0, myclass, LoadIcon(0,IDI_APPLICATION) };

if (RegisterClassEx(&wndclass))
{
    HWND window = CreateWindowEx(0, myclass, "title",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, 0, GetModuleHandle(0), 0);
    if (window)
    {
        ShowWindow(window, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
        MSG msg;
        while (GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0)) DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

**also outside the main, the new window**

```
long __stdcall WindowProcedure(HWND window, unsigned int msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp)
{ 
switch (msg)
{

case checksomethinghere: { 

}
default: // fall thru 

    return DefWindowProc(window, msg, wp, lp);
}
}
```

Now you can have your monitor window working in conjunction with your console, without blocking the console activity.

Tested, and working well.

From what I've read, you don't have to worry about calling CloseHandle for the created thread, because when the console is closed it will kill the thread and the window you created.

In my scenario the window and thread remain alive for the entire time the console app is running.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible to send messages to UI thread ?

Full example + PostMessage to UI thread ?

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <process.h>

UINT test_message = 0;
long __stdcall WindowProcedure(HWND window, unsigned int msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp)
{
    if (test_message == msg) {
        printf("Got it !\n"); // to console
        return 0;
    }
    else
        return DefWindowProc(window, msg, wp, lp);
}
static HWND window = NULL;
void SendMeMessage(HWND _window)
{
    window = _window;
    test_message = RegisterWindowMessage("TEST");
    PostMessage(window, test_message, 0, 0);
}

unsigned int __stdcall mythread(void* data)
{
    const LPCSTR myclass = "myclass";

    WNDCLASSEX wndclass = { sizeof(WNDCLASSEX), CS_DBLCLKS, WindowProcedure,
        0, 0, GetModuleHandle(0), LoadIcon(0,IDI_APPLICATION),
        LoadCursor(0,IDC_ARROW), HBRUSH(COLOR_WINDOW + 1),
        0, myclass, LoadIcon(0,IDI_APPLICATION) };

    if (RegisterClassEx(&wndclass))
    {
        window = CreateWindowEx(0, myclass, "title",
            WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
            CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, 0, GetModuleHandle(0), 0);
        if (window)
        {
            SendMeMessage(window);
            ShowWindow(window, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
            MSG msg;
            while (GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0)) DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    HANDLE myhandle;

    myhandle = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(0, 0, &mythread, 0, 0, 0);
    // ...
```